# Where are the DOM objects born?

Tags: javascript, dom

Please tell me where are DOM objects are kept. It seems that some part of browser (rendering engine or maybe browser engine) creating them and keeping them.
For example, if we have a tag  in HTML document, then DOM object is created, which inherits properties and methods from objects HTMLInputElement, HTMLElement, Element, Node, EventTarget, Object. It is not clear to me where they come from, seems that not from Javascript engine.

I cannot figure it out. Some people say that DOM-objects are Javascript objects, but not much. Pure JS-objects are created in JS engine.But DOM is written in C++ and allows to use DOM objects just like other JS objects. DOM objects look like other objects from JS language, and work like real JS objects.

How can these DOM-objects let create user-defined properties, that can bee "seen" in JS engine, if DOM-objects "live" not in JS engine?

I am coming to conclusion that DOM-objects are created in browser engine (ex Gecko). Which is written in C++. They inherit from classesNode, Element, HTMLElement
So it seems, that Node and HTMLElement - are host objects. In other words they are composed objects of browser engine Gecko, and not objects of JS engine. Some kind of instances of Gecko built-in classes.

3. But what the heck is Interface Definition Language?

Please show me where I am wrong in my understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please tell me where are DOM objects are kept.

That's an implementation detail that matters little unless you are writing a browser.

> How can these DOM-objects let create user-defined properties, that can bee "seen" in JS engine, if DOM-objects "live" not in JS engine?

The browser provides an API that exposes them to the JS engine.

> But what the heck is Interface Definition Language?

A way to describe the API so you know (for example) what methods are available on a type of object.